# Can't output int as result of sizeof()

Tags: c++, windows, windows-8, mingw, sizeof

I'm lloking to write a program in C++ which will sync two directories for me, and for part of it I need to get the size of an char array. The code I'm using is below

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    char binaryPath[MAX_PATH];
    GetModuleFileName(NULL, binaryPath, MAX_PATH);
    int r = sizeof(binaryPath);

    return 0;
}
```

Anyway, that code compiles and runs fine. The problem comes when I try and cout the binaryPath variable. In the main block, after the assignment/declaration of r if I try to output r to screen like so

```
cout << r;
```

the binary stops running. Windows says "Cpp.exe" has stopped working, and I am forced to force close the program. I have absolutely no idea why.

Even if I try much simpler versions, like the program below

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int r = 7;
cout << sizeof(r);
return 0;
}
```

the result is the same. It seems to me that I can pretty much do what I want with sizeof() behind the scenes, but as soon as I try and output it stuff stops working.

I'm using MinGW on a mac running windows 8 (b/c win8 has caused me some troubles in the past, not sure if it's managed to break c++).

Help is sorely needed and appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure what to tell you. This works fine when compiled by g++ and run on Mac OS X, as well as [g++ on ideone](http://ideone.com/tr8m5j). The problem may be with how your executable is built, the settings to the compler/linker, or the iostream library you are using.

Comment: The crash is likely caused by linking against the wrong libraries. My guess is the streams classes were built with different compilation flags causing their size to be different.

Comment: "I'm using MinGW on a mac running windows 8" - I think I begin to see your problem :-)

Comment: Do you mind if I edit the title of your question, as it's rather misleading. The problem isn't "getting the size of something", it is about outputting an integer...

Comment: Yeah... It's a convoluted setup to be sure although windows 8 causes all my problems. What's up with MinGW though?. Dave, could you possibly give me some random thoughts on what it might be? I know it's hard with so little information, but again, any help is nice. Basically though I installed MinGW with all default settings, and am using the Eclipse CDT for coding in c++

Comment: And captain oblivious could you elaborate on this?

Comment: Try compiling with the following options to see what libraries are being linked in: `g++ -v foo.cpp -Wl,--verbose`

Comment: [Here's](http://pastebin.com/tk0cNpBe) a pastebin of the verbose command

Comment: Alright, thanks for the help. I ended up re installing MinGW, and that seemed to fix the problem (although I got the same list of errors by compiling verbosely, not sure why). Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstall MinGW. That worked for me. Make sure to run the setup as admin though

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof()` will give you the size of the object. That is `MAX_PATH`, not the length of the string inside it. Use `strlen` for that.

Comment: Sage advice but has absolutely nothing to do with the problem at hand. Outputting the result of a `sizeof` should be little different to outputting the result of a `strlen`.

Comment: This is true, but not the reason why he's crashing/hanging, but good for him to know, so he's not asking about it after he finds and fixes the first problem. :)

Comment: Yes, I did sort of realize that. Not sure what is wrong with that - I can only presume it's something to do with the linking/compiling/compatibility in the system... My excuse is that I read the title of the question, looked at the code and thought I knew what the OP was asking..

Comment: Sorry, my title was rather misleading. For those uninformed my question title was originally asking how to get the size of an array, and the entire problem with sizeof() was added on as an afterthought in the topic when, in fact, it was the main problem. Solid answer though, I'll try it and mark yours as the answer in my other thread