# How can I calculate the number of elements in a char array?

Tags: c++, windows, string, char, sizeof

I was trying to calculate the number of elements in an array, and was told that the line

```
int r = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0])
```

would give me the number of elements in the array. And I found the method does work, at least for int arrays. When I try this code, however, things break.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    char binaryPath[MAX_PATH];
    GetModuleFileName(NULL, binaryPath, MAX_PATH);
    cout << "binaryPath: " << binaryPath << endl;
    cout << "sizeof(binaryPath): " << sizeof(binaryPath) << endl;
    cout << "sizeof(binaryPath[0]: " << sizeof(binaryPath[0]) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

When this program runs binaryPath's value is

```
C:\Users\Anish\workspace\CppSync\Debug\CppSync.exe
```

which seems to have a size returned by sizeof (in bytes? bits? idk, could someone explain this too?) of 260. The line

```
sizeof(binaryPath[0]);
```

gives a value of 1.

Obviously then dividing 260 by one gives a result of 260, which is not the number of elements in the array (by my count it's 42 or so). Could someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

I have a sneaking suspicion that isn't actually an array as I think of it (I come from Java and python), but I'm not sure so I'm asking you guys.

Thanks!

Comment: Like I said as an answer to this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16049936/cant-output-int-as-result-of-sizeof
But I was told that it wasn't the right answer because it had nothing to do with why your code was crashing. Perhaps you'd like to go back to that question and explain (in case someone else runs into a similar proble) what the fix was...

Comment: On a totally different note, did you write `using namespace std;` there, or was it put in by some tool? Just looking for information, no judgments involved.

Comment: The number of elements of your `char` array is `MAX_PATH`. It is as simple as that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are looking for the size of the string then you need to use [`strlen`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strlen), if you use `sizeof` it will tell you the allocated amount not the size of the null terminated string:

```
std::cout << "strlen(binaryPath: " << strlen(binaryPath) << std::endl;
```

You will need to add `#include <cstring>` on the top.

Answer (score 7):

260 is `MAX_PATH`, which you're getting because `sizeof` returns the size of the entire array - not just the size of the string inside the array.

To get the behavior you're looking for, use `strlen` instead:

```
cout << "binaryPath: " << binaryPath << endl;
cout << "strlen(binaryPath): " << strlen(binaryPath) << endl;
```

Answer (score 3):

You are confusing the size of the array with the length of the string it contains. `sizeof(arrayVar)` gives you the entire size of the array regardless of how long the string it contains is. You need to use `strlen()` to determine the actual length of the string it contains.

Answer (score 3):

Recall that char arrays in C++ and C are used to store raw character strings, and that such strings' ending is marked by a null character.

The operator `sizeof` is **not dynamic**: it will give you the size of the whole array, or whichever type you provide *in bytes* (or char, since they have the same size), as defined in your code. Hence *260* is certainly the value of `MAX_PATH`, which is used to define the char array `binaryPath`.

The string which is stored in that array after the call to `GetModuleFilename` will be null terminated, as per the convention stated above. In order to get its length you need to count the characters in it until you reach the null char or use the `strlen` function provided by the C library.

Some pointers:

- [What does sizeof do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203162/what-does-sizeof-do)
- [strlen](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strlen)